# How to emulate skins (from ASP.NET) in windows forms

Tags: windows, winforms

Here is the problem. i am developing a windows forms application in c# that has a lot of forms that include datagridviews, and i want to all those gridviews have the same look, same background color, same header alignment, and a lot of other properties.
in ASP.NET it is easy to do with skins, but how can i do this in windows forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create  a user control. Assign the properties whatever you want and then inherit that user control in the forms. Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to use 3rd party cntrols like [devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/). They have rich skin support and skin editor